# VSCode Debugger Exits out on sys functions

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I am new to python and using the VSCode or any IDE but I have one python file that gets imported by another. I am trying to run a debug so that I can step through the functions. However the first python file has sys functions that the debugger exits out on and I can't get past to my actual code where the functions are called from the second python file that I wrote. Example of that is:

```
import sys
import second_file as second

if __name__ =="__main__":
    if len(sys.argv)!=2:
             print("Usage: python first_file.py <filename>")
             sys.exit(1)  //Debugger exits out here

    inf = open(sys.argv[1]) //List index out of range error and exits out
```

I was trying to configure the launch json file to somehow work this out and was playing with the args values in the module but so far no luck.

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [

        {
            "name": "Python: Module",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "module": "Import_module",
            "args":["argv1","argv2","exit"]
        },
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal"
        }
    ]
```

}

If anybody could point me to a right direction, I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: You need to indent your `print` and `sys` lines so they are treated as part of the `if` block.

Comment: @jdaz I apologize but I made edits to the indentation which I forgot when I was first typing the question here. The indentation already exists in the actual code. I am just trying to figure out how I can make the debugger not exit out at the sys.exit line. If I comment that line out then, it throws an index error at the next line. I am not sure if i can add something to the launch.json file so that it lets me skip over that to my actual code

Comment: I don't see any code in that example which actually calls your own code. Did you leave that out by accident? Otherwise that example would never go into your code since you never use it.